# ViewController allocation and deallocation problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have this 2 "Loops" in my App between my ViewController.

First Loop is the Game-loop. At first VC my Level is displayed. The second VC is my Game Screen and if the game is finished, my third VC will appear with bonus point, stars, and so on.

The second "Loop" are just three VC with swiping.

[image]

Ok, where is now the problem? i have problems with the deallocations. for example, overtime i swipe, my locations are going up in sínstruments, the curve is getting higher and higher...

also my game loop. i can't deallocate the vc before.

i think i didn't understand correctly how [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]; works.

is it right, that this method is always sent to the parent vc, and the parent vc deallocate the vc where i execute this method?

is the parent vc my initial vc?

how can i dismiss and deallocate my view controllers correctly in my "loops"?

now, my allocing curve in instruments is getting higher and higher at each level, and about level 18-21 my app is crashing, i think because of too much allocations.

can anyone tell me hoe i can solve my problems?

Comment: Have u created ARC project or non arc ?

Comment: oh sorry, arc is enabled, i forget.

Comment: Still issue is facing or resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

**To begin with your questions:**

- Is it right that this method is always sent to the parent vc, and the parent vc deallocate the vc where I execute this method?

From the Documentation about `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion`:

> The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view
>   controller it presented. If you call this method on the presented view
>   controller itself, UIKit asks the presenting view controller to handle
>   the dismissal.

- Is the parent vc my initial vc?

Parenting is a bit complex with your structure. Normally, when a VC (let's call it X) presents another VC (this one is Y), X would be the parent of Y. But you must share additional code such as how you're allocating these VC's, how/when you're presenting them, etc. to know which one is the "most" parent.

When you call `[self presentViewController:Y animated:** completion:**` on X;

> X would be the `presentingViewController`.
>
> Y would be the `presentedViewController`.

Hence, X is the responsible one for Y. Parent :) So, your question is a bit invalid for your scheme. However, you can easily say that your initial VC would probably be the parent of all VC's that's presented by him. (For example, if you embed navigation controller for VC's, it would be the root VC and it will be responsible for "winding/unwinding", which makes it "parent".)

Normally, view controllers should not go in a loop between themselves. They can be dependable on each other, but it shouldn't create loops.

**Solution proposal:**

It seems to me that you're duplicating these 3 kind of VC's every time a level begins. That's the first loop's problem. The second loop is a bit complex, I assume you want to save the state of the VC's while swiping to the other VC's.

*1. Manipulating current VCs.*

These VCs must have an option to clear his state, everything should be reset like it was loaded for the first time. You will only create these VCs **once**, and reset them if needed.

*2. Create a Singleton Class which will hold these VCs.*

(Caution: Since this solution involves holding VCs up in a class, they will always hold up memory. They won't be drawn to window, though.)

When you start the app, a singleton will be created, and you will also create the VCs needed at the same time. This class should have methods like:

```
addViewControllerToStack:
showViewController:animated:completion:
resetViewController:
```

And of course properties to hold these VCs.

*3. Control through Singleton*

When the user presses up a button like "go to X level", you must interact with the Singleton class you've created. If you're going to dismiss a VC, the Singleton should do that. Also for presentation.

**Summary:**

With this method, you cannot create multiple VCs of the same type. You can always use the one which is created by your Singleton class, and you can always reuse them. But be cautious, since you're not deallocating any VC, you may end up with residues (like forgetting to reset/remove timers, to reset score, etc).

I've used it in one of my project, which required a view controller with OpenGL. I couldn't dismiss it since it's always doing calculations. And it could've been created only once. The bad part is, it was in the middle of the VC segues. So, whenever I needed to present that VC, I call my Singleton class to show it for me. And I create it only once.